# SqlStorage Ionic 2 as a service/provider

Tags: javascript, sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a provider in ionic two, and I have this:

```
getCategory() {
    this.storage.query('SELECT * FROM category')
      .then((data) => {
        var category = [];
        if (data.res.rows.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < data.res.rows.length; i++) {
            category.push({
              name: data.res.rows.item(i).name,
              type: data.res.rows.item(i).type,
              note: data.res.rows.item(i).note
            });
          }
        }
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(category)); 
        return category; // is this correct?
      }, (error) => {
        console.log('Error -> ' + JSON.stringify(error.err));
      });
  }
```

Then I wish to do something like this in my pages, after injecting the service:

```
  constructor(nav, theservice) {
    this.nav = nav;
    this.service = theservice
    this.category = service.getCategory()
  }
```

How do I return something the results in order to be able to use? Trying the above returns nothing when I console log `this.category`

The tutorial on [how to use sqlite in ionic 2](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/12/use-sqlite-in-ionic-2-instead-of-local-storage/) has been helpful, but couldn't figure out how to convert them into services/providers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE (June 15, '16)**

I shared a link in my original answer below. More discussions happened on the thread, and earlier answer approach, although works, might not be best practice. Update here:

`service.js`

```
// using beta 7 ionic 2
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Storage, SqlStorage } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {
  static get parameters(){
    return []
  }  

  constructor() {
    this.storage = new Storage(SqlStorage);
    this.storage.query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, type TEXT)');
  }

  getCategory() {
    return this.storage.query('SELECT id, name, type FROM category');
  }
}
```

Then the service above is used like this:

`somewhereInCategoryPage.js` file

```
 loadCategory() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.service.getCategory()
        .then(data => {
          this.category = [];
          if (data.res.rows.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.res.rows.length; i++) {
              let item = data.res.rows.item(i);
              this.category.push({
                'id': item.id,
                'name': item.name,
                'type': item.type
              });
            }
          }
          console.log(this.category);
        }, error => {
          console.log('Error', error.err)
        })
    });
  }
```

Just thought of updating, might be useful for who-knows.

---

**Old Answer** Leaving here for reference

What I settled on finally. Posting here, might help someone. Guidance from [this thread on ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/sqlite-queries-as-a-service-provider/52000)

in the service/provider

```
getCategory() {
   var storage = new Storage(SqlStorage);
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       return storage.query('SELECT name, type, note FROM category')
          .then((data) => {
             // kinda lazy workaround
             resolve(data.res.rows);
           });
        });
   }
```

in constructor:

```
static get parameters() {
    return [ [Myservice] ];
}
constructor(myservice) {
  myservice.getCategory()
  .then((category) => {
    // recreate new array from old category array, or else:
    // EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object
    // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6392#issuecomment-171428006
    this.categories = Array.from(category);
    console.log(this.categories);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

in template:

```
<ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="#category of categories">
        {{ category.name }}
        <br>
        <ion-icon name="arrow-forward" item-right></ion-icon>
    </button>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: This looks better, still for the record, I think in your original example this small change would make it work: service.getCategory().then( (category) => { this.category = category})

Comment: @ManuValdés the error from my original example complained of the getCategory() not being a promise. Promises have the `then`s, but in my original example, it wasn't

Comment: oh yes that's right, it's missing a return statement in front of this.storage.query(...).then(....); that's how you return the then() (which is a  promise), that you can then chain in your page constructor.